# Error on installing Ssrs data connector

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am installing Srs Data Connector for MS Dynamics CRM, but on the systems checking were encountering an error "There is no such object on the server". I've tried googling it but to no avail.

**UPDATE:** Added some details

- I'm running on 2 VM one for CRM app and the other for MSSQL
- I'm installing the srs data connector to the MSSQL Server
- Both Server is running on Windows 2008 r2
- SQL Server is MSSQL 2008

  [image]

Comment: Could it be that you are trying to install the wrong version (CRM 2013) of the SSRS Data Connector?

Comment: But the installer of the Srsdataconnector came from the package folder of the CRM installer

Comment: Okay, so we can exclude the more obvious causes. Are all your services (CRM and SQL) running on the same machine? Maybe add some more details regarding your environment to your post (OS version, SQL Server version, etc.)

Comment: Hi I've edited the content and put some details of my environment Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could be the permissions issue. Make sure `NTAUTORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` have permissions to access `MSCRM_CONFIG`. You might also need to reset IIS on CRM Machine after sorting out the access issue.

Comment: Tried that but to no avail. I ended up redeploying the CRM and the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Is this on-prem?

If that's the case you may want to program in SQL as opposed to fetchxml - It's a lot more flexable.

That being said, if you want to continue to use fetchxml - make sure to point the ssrs data connector to your crm server and not the database server.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share the resolution and the cause of the problem (Well not the detailed cause).

The problem was caused by an issue on the AD configuration and the installation of the CRM and MSSQL.
After 2 weeks of trying to resolve various errors on the CRM installation including the above post the problem seems to be with the AD config.

We have many Domain controllers and changes on each DC were scheduled to be copied on the other controllers each afternoon. That's why some setup done by the CRM were not copied immediately.

We have tried re-installing the CRM and MSSQL but it also failed. The trick is to set up the CRM and MSSQL in the same DC then disable the CRM and MSSQL servers to connect to the other domain controller OR  to replicate the configurations in the DC in real time.

After that all errors and warnings will be gone...

Thanks,